# Mysterious loss of reputation

Tags: support, bug, reputation

I have recently noticed that I lose some 2-10 reputation points every day (been going on for about a week). I disregarded it because it was a very small amount and I used to think that my edits would have been overwritten (I don't think this happens though). Today, I lost around 20.

Worried by this, I checked my reputation notifications – no sign of downvotes/negative reputations here.
Then, I checked my reputation history – looking for reputation loss due to deletion of users' accounts – found none.

So here I am, looking for some reason. Why does this happen (mysteriously)? Is it because the community has decided to penalize me for any ill behavior? Or is there a different reason?

Comment: What to you see on [your reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation)? Do not forget to check the checkbox with "show removed posts".

Comment: @MartinSleziak that explains it all! I never noticed that tiny little checkbox. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed that the reputation loss was due to deletion of closed posts by user Community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gained that reputation for suggesting edits in the past, but those posts have now been deleted (either by an [automatic process](/help/roomba) or by trusted users) because they were low quality. In that case, you'll lose the +2 reputation from the suggested edit, because reputation is (generally) only gained from contributions which are still visible. For more details, see [Do you lose your +2 edit rep if the edited post is subsequently deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78147/295232)

@MartinSleziak wrote a helpful [Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1336586/recent-suggested-edits-by-a-specific-user?userid=734160) and you can see from the first column that some of the posts no longer exist. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1481390) is an example of such a post.

Comment: This is indeed a plausible explanation, considering small losses. However losing a bunch of them periodically seems fishy....

Comment: Looking at the [suggested edits by this user in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1336586/recent-suggested-edits-by-a-specific-user?userid=734160), there are indeed some deleted posts.

Comment: It is probably not that important, but I'll just add that the SuggestedEdits table keeps the data also about deleted posts. At least that is what I gather from [the above query restricted to deleted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1336617/recent-suggested-edits-by-a-specific-user-on-deleted-posts?userid=734160) and [similar query without the restriction on a single user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1336618/recent-suggested-edits-on-post-which-are-now-deleted). So I think that the claim that "they won't be visible there anymore" is not correct.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ah right, because it's actually some kind of review record. Thanks for spotting that (and for writing the query).

Comment: Nitpick: Why do I lose reputation points when a post is deleted? I might agree that it no longer contributes to the site. But it may help the OP, as in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGZ0k.png) case.

Comment: Because you also gain lost reputation back when a downvoted post is deleted. Symmetry for the win! There's one exception if the post is >60 days old and has a score of 3 or higher: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141682/295232