# List of edits waiting for approval

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I want to see the list of all my edits that are still waiting for an approval. Does such a list exist?
If yes, where/how can I see/get such a list?

Comment: I would try the Suggestions subtab of the All Actions tab of your Activities page.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1050858/inanimatebeing?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). It seems that there is no suggestion that is pending approval now.

Comment: @hardmath I can only see the ones that are approved though it could be the case that none are waiting for approval at the moment and so I won't know if it works/shows the waiting ones in general.

Comment: @ArcticChar alright thanks a lot. Also, may I expand my question to ask for the ones that are rejected or ignored?

Comment: Rejected suggestion can also be found in the same link. If I understand correctly, suggestions are never ignored.

Comment: Is it [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503029/if-cosa-b-1-2-and-sinab-1-2-find-the-smallest-positive-values-of)?

Comment: In that case, your edit suggestion is not ignord. It is [rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1825719) and edited by the same user. I guess that they find the use of $\cos$, $\sin$ better than the $Cos$, $Sin$ that you used.

Comment: There is a section "How can I check on my own suggested edits?" in the FAQ post: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251) As mentioned in the above comment, you can find them [in your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions),

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see list of all your suggested edits in your profile, if you go to "all actions" and then choose the [suggestions tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). This is also mentioned in the FAQ post: There is a section "How can I check on my own suggested edits?" in the FAQ post: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)

I will add this [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) query: [Recent suggested edits by a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1336586/recent-suggested-edits-by-a-specific-user?userid=1050858). The database is only updated once a week - so you won't see the most recent edits here. But the advantage is that if the question was deleted in the meantime, the edit is still shown in this list. (The same query was linked in this answer: [Mysterious loss of reputation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32793#32794). And here is another query which list [only the suggested edits on deleted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1336617/recent-suggested-edits-by-a-specific-user-on-deleted-posts?userid=1050858).)